# Python pisa multipage alignment issue

Tags: python, django, reportlab, pisa, xhtml2pdf

I am using **xhtml2pdf ver. 0.0.6** and **reportlab ver. 2.7** in my app which uses **django 1.6.6**, for my pdf generation. I need to generate yearly reports with data being taken from the database. I use **pisa 0.3.3 in xhtml2pdf** module and can generate pdf correctly when the data is one page long. But **when the** **data exceeds one page**, I am getting alignment issue with **table header in the first page and subsequent row of data in the next page**. The code I use for pdf generation is given below :

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    @page {
        size: a4 portrait;
        margin: 1cm 2cm;
        margin-bottom: 1.5cm;
        padding:0;

        @frame footer {
                   -pdf-frame-content: footer-content;
                   bottom: 0.5cm;
                   margin-left: 2cm;
                   margin-right: 2cm;
                   height: 0.5cm;
        }
    }

    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        -pdf-outline: false;
    }

    img {
        zoom: 80%;
    }

    .logo {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>

    <table class="table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 30%; font-size: 12px; text-align: left;">Col1</th>
        <th style="width: 20%; font-size: 12px; text-align: right">Col2</th>
        <th style="width: 30%;font-size: 12px; text-align: left;">Col3</th>
        <th style="width: 20%;font-size: 12px; text-align: right;">Col4</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align:top">
                <table class="table-no-border" style="width:100%;">
                    <tbody>

                    {% for obj in objects %}
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: left;">{{ obj.account__name }}</td>
                                <td style="text-align: right">{{ balance|floatformat:2|comma_sep_num }}</td>
                            </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">Profit/Loss</td>
                            <td style="text-align: right">{{ object.profit_loss|floatformat:2|comma_sep_num }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
        </td>
        <td  colspan="2"  style="vertical-align:top">
                <table  class="table-no-border" style="width:100%;">
                    <tbody>
                    {% for obj in inc_objects %}
                        {% if obj.credit_amount__sum > obj.debit_amount__sum %}
                          {% math obj.credit_amount__sum obj.debit_amount__sum "$1 - $2" as balance %}
                        {% else %}
                          {% math obj.debit_amount__sum obj.credit_amount__sum "$1 - $2" as balance %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if balance %}
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: left;">{{ obj.account__name }}</td>
                                <td style="text-align: right">{{ balance|floatformat:2|comma_sep_num }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if  profit_loss < 0 %}
                        {% math profit_loss "-1 * $1" as profit_loss %}
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">Excess of expense over income</td>
                            <td style="text-align: right">{{ profit_loss|abs|floatformat:2|comma_sep_num }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% math inc_total profit_loss|abs "$1 + $2" as inc_total %}
                    {% endif %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;font-weight: bold;">{{ exp_total|floatformat:2|comma_sep_num }}</td>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;font-weight: bold;">{{ inc_total|floatformat:2|comma_sep_num }}</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Please revert with your valuable stips/suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need so many nested tables? Can you show what are you expecting and what do you get?

Comment: I have a reporting system which has 2 columns and 2 rows .First row has headings. In the next row with colspan='2',  I display database values in a table with 2 columns and 'n' rows. Output pdf is like a list of categories and their rates. For small number of data, the pdf is displaying perfectly with categories under the first column and rate under the second. For large data, the first page of pdf has only the heading while the categories are displayed in the  next page.